# What is the halachic punishment for not showing respect?

Tags: halacha, kavod

Specifically for the mitzvah of כבוד לחכמים, what is the punishment a person is given?  I'm looking mainly for the divine punishment, but if human punishment applies I'd like that too.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites) and thanks for this first question.

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. Hope to see you around !

Comment: Do you mean a divine punishment, or one meted out by man?

Comment: Divine punishment I assume but if both apply it would be helpful to know both.

Comment: Does not showing respect include actively denigrating? Or is this just asking about the lack of showing positive respect even without actively denigrating?

Comment: It seems that it is death. That's based, partially on the story / explanation that the main reason that Rabbi Akiva's students died is due to lack of respect for each other. And, they were all considered "chachamim".

Comment: @DanF Maybe the inference is that anyone who is disrespectful towards someone else merits death. Who says it was because they were hakhamim? Who says they were even hakhamim?

Comment: According to one view in Sanhedrin (99b), one who denigrates a Torah scholar is considered an epikoros; a heretic.

In this vein, Rambam writes in Hilkhot Teshuva (3:14), that such a person has no share in the world to come. He clarifies that this refers to one who does so frequently. See also Massekhet Kallah (ch. 3) that implies that this applies to speaking disrespectfully.

Additionally, Rambam writes in Hilkhot Talmud Torah (6:11) that it is a great sin to hate the Sages or to degrade them, and that Jerusalem was destroyed when people shamed Torah scholars.

Comment: @mevaqesh Looks like answer material.

Comment: How do you know that this is even a sin? Perhaps it’s just good middos to respect our leaders. Could you please edit in a source for that claim? Also, knowing the source can help narrow down the answer (is it an explicit verse or derived, is it a positive or a negative, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the story of "shviskel" near the beginning of the forth chapter of mesechet Kedushin we see that both excommunication (nidui) and flogging are appropriate punishments for disrespect to rabbis and their emissaries.  This is by human hands. (although nidui might involve heavenly punishment)

Comment: The relevant story is 70a-b. The short version is that Rav Yehudah bar Yechezkel excommunicated a person who derogatorily referred to him as Rav Yehudah bar Sheviskel (“the glutton” - see Rashi). It’s a fascinating story that you should read (probably one of my favorite stories in the Gemara), but that beginning part (or, more directly, the portion on 70b where this ruling is upheld) is the only relevant piece to this discussion. Nevertheless, I must question this: Was nidui actually the appropriate punishment, or did Rav Yehudah merely punish him this way to prove a point?

Comment: Indeed rashi calls it a knas